# Cant't assign to array vba

Tags: arrays, json, vba, excel

I'm having trouble in my code and i dont know why.. in thhis line "Key = decode.GetKeys(issue)" raises the error mentioned on the title of this question.

```
Public Sub Import_JSON_From_URL(url As JiraJSONGet)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawData").Activate
result = url.LoadJson

Dim total As Long
total = getLastRow()


doInit
Dim Keys() As String
Keys = decode.GetKeys(JsonObject)
Dim issues As Object
Set issues = decode.GetObjectProperty(JsonObject, Keys(4))
Dim field, issue_project, issue_type, issue_status, issue_summary, issue_report, issue_created, issue_updated, issue_assignee, issue_priority, issue_resolution, issue_resolved, issue_time_spent, issue_time_estimated, issue_project_type As Object

Dim Key(), k_fields(), k_project(), k_issuetype(), k_status(), k_summary(), k_report(), k_created(), k_updated(), k_assignee(), k_priority(), k_resolution(), k_resolved(), k_timespent(), k_timeestimated(), k_projecttype() As String

Dim issue, ki, kf, kproject, kissuetype, kstatus, ksummary, kreport, kcreated, kupdated, kassignee, kpriority, kresolution, kresolved, ktimespent, ktimeestimated As Variant

Dim project_name_issue, project_key_issue, key_issue, issue_type_name, issue_type_description, status_name_issue, summary_key, report_key, created, updated, assignee, priority, resolution, resolved, timespent, timeestimated, today As String
For Each issue In issues
        Key = decode.GetKeys(issue)
        For Each ki In Key
            If ki = "key" Then
                key_issue = decode.GetProperty(issue, ki)
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawData").Range("A" & total + 1).value = key_issue
            End If
            If ki = "fields" Then
                Set field = decode.GetObjectProperty(issue, ki)
                k_fields = decode.GetKeys(field)
                For Each kf In k_fields
```

I have a class named JSONDecoder, with GetKeys function in it:

```
Public Function GetKeys(ByVal JsonObject As Object) As String()
    Dim length As Integer
    Dim KeysArray() As String
    Dim KeysObject As Object
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim value As Variant

    Set KeysObject = ScriptEngine.Run("getKeys", JsonObject)
    length = GetProperty(KeysObject, "length")
    ReDim KeysArray(length - 1)
    index = 0
    For Each Key In KeysObject
        KeysArray(index) = Key
        index = index + 1
    Next
    GetKeys = KeysArray
    'value = GetProperty(JsonObject, "issues")
    'Set value = GetObjectProperty(JsonObject, "issues")

End Function
```

Comment: where do you get the error and can you quote the error description?

Comment: What is the actual line the error occurs on? Also, in VBA, always specify the data type for everything you are declaring as it can cause subtle issues. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369229/crazy-issue-with-string-formatting/33370612#33370612) for details on how it can cause subtle issues.

Comment: Here: Key = decode.GetKeys(issue)

Comment: Post the code for GetKeys as well. We're not psychic :)

Comment: can't read it in comments. please edit your question to include the formatted code. Also post the EXACT error message that shows up when you run your code.

Comment: how and where do you declare and initialize the decode object? Also, are you sure the error is not within the GetKEys method? With no error handling, the error will get kicked out to the calling function. Have you stepped through the code?

Comment: I  call this function on a method ---> 
Dim jiraJsonGetter As New JiraJSONGet
    Call jiraJsonGetter.init(importerConfig, importerConfig.JQLQuery, False)
  Call clsJira.Import_JSON_From_URL(jiraJsonGetter)


But the GetKeys function is not called because the debug mode raises the error on the variable Key.

Comment: I have a feeling your error is inside the GetKeys function. Set a breakpoint inside the function, then step through and see what line errors.

Comment: If I had to predict, I would say that it would error on the "KeysArray(index) = Key" line in the GetKeys function.

Comment: The problem is the first error being in the instruction Key = decode.GetKeys(issue) i cant go into the function... i have the error and the program shuts down

Comment: I try to put a breakpoint on the GetKeys function and in the line of code and nothing...

Comment: what version of excel are you using?

Comment: I use microsoft office excel 2013

Comment: not sure. your error must be somewhere else. I posted some sample array code that works fine.

Comment: FYI after  `dim a, b, c as T` only `c` if of type `T` the remainder are variants. Correct: `dim a as T, b as T, c as T`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where your issue is.
I tested returning an array of strings from both a regular function and using a class, and both work fine, however you state your code will not even compile.
Your issue must be somewhere else.

Module code:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim result() As String

    result = Test1

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To 3
        Debug.Print result(i)
    Next

    Dim c As New clsTest

    result = c.CreateStrings

    For i = 0 To 3
        Debug.Print result(i)
    Next

End Sub

Function Test1() As String()
    Dim s() As String

    ReDim s(3)

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To 3
        s(i) = "blah" & i
    Next

    Test1 = s

End Function
```

Class code:

```
Public Function CreateStrings() As String()
    Dim r() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    ReDim r(3)

    For i = 0 To 3

        r(i) = "class blah" & i

    Next

    CreateStrings = r

End Function
```